# How to initialize two canvases in two different frames of tkinter gui properly?

Tags: python, user-interface, canvas, tkinter, initialization

I followed the code of https://pythonprogramming.net/how-to-embed-matplotlib-graph-tkinter-gui/
I only changed it in this way, that I have two pages, each with one canvas.

My problem is, that when I initialize the GUI it takes a lot of time and it looks like it freezes for some seconds at another page than the start page "ChooseSensor".

I would be greatful for any suggestions, how I can initialize it properly.

Here is my code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style 



#define LARGE_FONT
LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)
style.use('ggplot')

#define figures
#figure for canvas sensor1
f1 = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi = 100)
a1 = f1.add_subplot(111)

#figure for canvas sensor2
f2 = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi = 100)
a2 = f2.add_subplot(111)


class Sensors(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs ):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill = "both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}

        for F in (ChooseSensor, Sensor1, Sensor2):   
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
         self.show_frame(ChooseSensor)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class ChooseSensor(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text = "Sensor Auswahl", font= LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self,text="Sensor 1",
                            command=lambda:controller.show_frame(Sensor1))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self,text="Sensor 2",
                            command=lambda:controller.show_frame(Sensor2))
        button2.pack()


class Sensor1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text = "Sensor 1", font= LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        button1 = tk.Button(self,text="back to home",
                         command=lambda:controller.show_frame(ChooseSensor))
        button1.pack()

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f1, self)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill = tk.BOTH, expand = True)



class Sensor2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text = "Sensor 2", font= LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        button1 = tk.Button(self,text="back to home",
                        command=lambda:controller.show_frame(ChooseSensor))
        button1.pack()

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f2, self)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill = tk.BOTH, expand = True)



app = Sensors()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: put `print()` in many places to find out which part of code runs slower.

Comment: It doesn't really feel slow on my end, windows 7 here.

Comment: I agree with @Nae, it isn't slow at all on my windows 10 comp.

Comment: So is the first page you can see the 'ChooseSensor' page? Because when I initialize the gui, it looks like it would raise the other windows at first